# Numpy image array set pixel dimension values based on binary categories

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a CNN project using brain MRI data. The image labels are in a large numpy array of shape `(20636, 240, 240, 3)`. The 3rd dimension holds the pixel values as binary data based on tumor tissue criteria, where it can be one of:

```
     [0,0,0]
     [0,0,1]
     [0,1,0]
     [1,0,0]
```

I'm am needing to create a new label array where instead of these tissue categories, I simply have an array the specifies the label pixels as either tumor/not tumor, but keeps the original shape. I thought I could do this by masking where any pixels are == 1 and setting `data[:,:,:,0:1] = 1`, and then setting all values of `data[:,:,:,1:3] = 0`.

So far what I know of slicing/indexing is failing me with this problem, so I know I'm missing something probably pretty straight-forward. What I've tried hasn't even gotten me close.

Comment: Let me know if I understood this well or not, if there's a 1 in the last dimension, you want it to be in the first index and the rest of indices be 0 on that dimension. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply sort along the last axis:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>     
# create example                                                                                                            
>>> a = np.identity(4, int)[np.random.randint(0, 4, (2, 2, 2)), :-1]                            
>>> a                                                                                                               
array([[[[1, 0, 0],                                                                                                 
         [0, 0, 1]],                                                                                                

        [[0, 0, 1],                                                                                                 
         [0, 0, 0]]],                                                                                               


       [[[0, 0, 1],                                                                                                 
         [1, 0, 0]],                                                                                                

        [[0, 0, 0],                                                                                                 
         [0, 0, 1]]]])                                                                                              
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> b = a.copy()
# flip last axis to obtain descending order
>>> b[..., ::-1].sort(axis=-1)
>>> b                                                                                                               
array([[[[1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]]],


       [[[1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0]]]])
```

### Other methods:

1) preallocate

```
>>> b = np.zeros_like(a)
>>> b[..., 0] = a.any(axis=-1)
```

2) Kronecker product

```
>>> np.kron(a.any(axis=-1, keepdims=True), (1,0,0))
```

3) outer product

```
>>> np.multiply.outer(a.any(axis=-1), (1,0,0))
```

4) fancy indexing

```
>>> np.outer((0,1), (1,0,0))[a.any(axis=-1).view(np.uint8)]
```